# How to do a slideshow in HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I want to do a slideshow like this one : https://www.inextenso.digital/about-us/ (at the end of the page)

But I'm a beginer in HTML and CSS.. I don't arrive to make the block exceeding the parent block and add padding beetwin my blocks..I can't add picture because I'm too new on this website but maybe you can undertstand if you see my code.

I know nothing about the CSS animation and all of the slideshow I found in google somes slideshows but each time it's for 3 or 4 pictures and they take all of the screen but it's not what I'm looking for..

```css
.slider-container {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 50vh;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  padding: 30px;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.slider-image {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 20vw;
}


/* 

.image-container {
    width: 3000px;
    height: 400px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;

    animation-name: slider;
    animation-duration: 12s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    animation-play-state: running;
}


.slider-image {
 width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}


@keyframes slider {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translate(-1000px, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-2000px, 0);
    }
}

.un {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.deux {
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.trois {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
} */
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="slider-image un">1</div>
    <div class="slider-image deux">2</div>
    <div class="slider-image trois">3</div>
    <div class="slider-image quatre">4</div>
    <div class="slider-image cinq">5</div>
    <div class="slider-image six">6</div>
    <div class="slider-image sept">7</div>
    <div class="slider-image huit">8</div>
    <div class="slider-image neuf">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use the [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) library (working with [JQuery](https://jquery.com/)), which allows you to create carousels very easily.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

// add these javascript

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>

<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="slider-image un">1</div>
    <div class="slider-image deux">2</div>
    <div class="slider-image trois">3</div>
    <div class="slider-image quatre">4</div>
    <div class="slider-image cinq">5</div>
    <div class="slider-image six">6</div>
    <div class="slider-image sept">7</div>
    <div class="slider-image huit">8</div>
    <div class="slider-image neuf">9</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.slider-image').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
                nextArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right nextArrowBtn"></i>',
                prevArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left prevArrowBtn"></i>',
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 8000
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for every answer ! I'm gonna try everything tonight